# Why does this method of converting a number with base 10 to its equivalent in base 2 always work?

Tags: number-theory

I read about a method to convert any number with base 10(i.e., a decimal number)into one with base 2 (binary number). It involves repeated division with the quotients obtained in the preceding operation and continuing it until the quotient becomes 0. And all the remainders obtained in this manner,when written in the the order in which they are obtained,represent the binary equivalent of the given decimal number.
For example, binary equivalent
of 9(base 10) can be obtained as follows:-
9/2=2(4)+1
4=2(2)+0
2=2(1)+0
1=2(0)+1

Taking all the remainders in the order they are obtained,the binary equivalent  of 9(base 10) is 1001.

Now, what I can't understand is why this method works.There must be some proof or derivation of this rule.

Comment: What does 159 mean to you in base 10? Divide the number by 10 and you get 15 remainder 9 i.e 15 tens and a 9. Now divide 15 by 10 and you get 1 remainder 5 i.e 1 hundred and 5 tens. Divide the 1 by 10 and you get 0 i .e 1 hundred and nothing after that. So 159 = 100 + 5 * 10 + 9 with the convention that the higher powers of 10 are on the left. Doing this in base 2 is exactly the same thing.

Comment: On a separate note: Regarding the example in your problem: You say "Taking all the remainders in the order they are obtained, the binary equivalent of 9 (base 10) is 1001." Because 1001 is a palindrome it is not clear which order you are doing...I would say the implication in your statement is that the first 1 you get is the leftmost digit; but in fact the first remainder is the rightmost digit. That is, you are getting the bits from least significant (ones place) to most significant.

Comment: @DavidK , yes this is exactly what I needed. Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

If $a_0$ is the number we want to convert from base $10$ to base $2$, the method constructs two sequences by recursion:
$a_n = d(a_{n-1},2), \quad b_n = r(a_{n-1},2) ,\quad a_{n-1}=2 a_n + b_n$
where $d(a,2)=\lfloor \frac a 2 \rfloor$ is the integer division of $a$ by $2$,
and $r(a,2)=a-2 \; d(a,2)$ is the remainder of division of $a$ by $2$, i.e $a[2]$, $a$ modulo $2$.

Then, by recursion, $a_0 = \sum_{j=1}^k 2^{j-1} b_j + 2^k a_k$:

- This is true for $k=1$.
- $a_0 = \sum_{j=1}^k 2^{j-1} b_j + 2^k a_k$
  $= \sum_{j=1}^k 2^{j-1} b_j + 2^k (2 a_{k+1} + b_{k+1})$
  $= \sum_{j=1}^{k+1} 2^{j-1} b_j + 2^{k+1} a_{k+1}$

As $b_j$ are remainders of a division by $2$, their value is $0$ or $1$.

We stop when $a_n = 0$. At this step we have:
$a_0 = \sum_{j=1}^n 2^{j-1} b_j$
This is the decomposition of an integer in base $2$.